# Alexa Spelling Skill - How to trigger answer intent when a word is misspelledc

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am currently writing a alexa spelling skill to ask different spellings and to check user input according to the data we have. I created below intents & slots to do the expected work:

**Intents:**
SpellingIntent - Ask a random word from the list of words
AnswerIntent - Validate the user input

**Slots:**
Words - to keep track of all the words
Spellings - Spellings of words in dot separated format

For example if the word is apple, then spellings slot would have a.p.p.l.e

My app is working fine if the user spelled the word correctly, but if the user misspelled the word then I am not getting event till answerIntent to validate.

I researched about this and I found that amazon deprecated Amazon.LITERAL built in slot type to trigger any word spoken by user and I have to use SearchQuery. But I am not getting how to get the event fired to my answer intent whatever the user said.

Could anyone help me out to figure this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I would suggest trying the following as a solution.

1 - Stop using `AMAZON.SearchQuery`, instead define a custom slot value like the below:

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "LETTER",
      "values": [
        {
          "name": {
            "value": "a",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "value": "b",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "value": "c",
            "synonyms": []
          }
        },

        // ... and so on

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

2 - Redefine your `AnswerIntent` to accept varying quantities of the `LETTER` slot value, like the below:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "AnswerIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "LetterOne",
          "type": "LETTER"
        },
        {
          "name": "LetterTwo",
          "type": "LETTER"
        },
        {
          "name": "LetterThree",
          "type": "LETTER"
        },

        // ... and so on

      ],
      "samples": [
        "{LetterOne}",
        "{LetterOne} {LetterTwo}",
        "{LetterOne} {LetterTwo} {LetterThree}",

        // ... and so on

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In theory, this set up should trigger the `AnswerIntent` any time a user speaks a sequence of letters. You should then be able to collect the letters passed through in slot values and compare them against the correct spelling.

As a potential additional step you could try adding synonyms to the slot values for phonetically matching words such as the below. Then access the slots in your code via the key value.

```
{
  "name": {
    "value": "b",
    "synonyms": [
      "be",
      "bee"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting issues while trying to capture user spoken letters in answerIntent. I am trying to get answer like - let answer = intent['slots']['LETTER']['value']. Getting undefined error while doing so. Can you let me know how to resolve it

Comment: So your `AnswerIntent` is now triggering? This is a separate issue from your original post. It also requires more clarification (ie. What is the utterance you are triggering the intent with? How many slots does the intent have? How many values are captured and what are they?).

Comment: I created LETTER types and utterances as suggested but getting error in answerIntent while trying to speak sample word "abcdef" at line number 164 of index.js in my github project given below: https://github.com/uday060/AlexaSpellChecker/blob/master/src/index.js .           
Here is the code which causing issues.  let answer = intent['slots']['LETTER']['value'].          Could you please go through once and let me know once what I'm missing here

Comment: If you log your intent object the answer to your problem should become clear. `LETTER` is not the *name* of any of your slots, it is their *type*. You are getting an undefined error because `intent.slots.LETTER` does not exist and as such you cannot check the `value` property on it. You need to check for values on `intent.slots.LetterOne`, `intent.slots.LetterTwo` etc.